# sql, select only such rows that share a predefined value

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to select such rows that have the same specific value in one of the columns. For example, in the table below there are airlines that fly to different cities. I need to select only such airlines that fly exclusively to the usa. In the table below that would be only the airline2. The city is basically not important for the moment.

```
airline country_destination city_destination
airline1 usa washington
airline1 eng london
airline1 fra paris
airline2 usa new york
airline2 usa chicago
airline2 usa washington
airline3 can montreal
airline3 usa new york
airline3 can toronto
```

My first guess returns all the airlines, because in every of them the usa appears at least once.

```
select distinct airline from table1 where country_destination = 'usa'
```

I assume I need a nested 'select' and probably a group by airlines? Somewhere directionof what I have below? But I am stuck at this point. Any help is highly appreciated!

```
select airline, country_destination
from (select airline, country_destination from table1 where country_destination = 'usa' group by airline)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do need to aggregate.

This is the simplest way I know of to do it:

```
select airline
  from table1
 group by airline
having min(country_destination) = max(country_destination) 
   and min(country_destination) = 'usa';
```

Answer (score 2):

One method is to check if the airline's row count matches the conditional count (in this case, the amount of rows where the destination is 'usa').

The CTE aggregates the airline data. In the SELECT-statement you can apply the filter to only include airlines where the total row count equals the row count for destination 'usa'. If the counts between `count_all` and `count_usa` differ you know there were other country destinations.

```
with counts as ( select airline,
                        count(*) as count_all,
                        sum(case when country_destination == 'usa' then 1 end) as count_usa
                 from table1
                 group by 1 )
select airline
from counts
where count_all = count_usa;
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use below with inner query-

```
select *  from 
(select distinct airline, country_destination from table1 ) t 
group by airline 
having count(airline) = 1 AND country_destination='usa';
```